# Perl editing the files

Tags: regex, perl

My file contains 100 lines

```
1234 ABC 100.0.0.0 
4567 DEF 200.0.0.0 .....
```

I am matching a pattern in my file. for example search for `4567` and replace the `200.0.0.0` to `500.0.0.0`, so that line looks now `4567 DEF 500.0.0.0`.

```
my $file = "$file_path/file.lst";
my $newid = "500.0.0.0"
open MAST, $file or die "Unable to open file.lst: $!";
my $new = "$file.tmp.$$";
my $bak = "$file.bak";
open(NEW, "> $new")         or die "can't open $new: $!";

while (<MAST>) {
my ($pattern,$id) = (split /\s+/, $_)[0,4];
        print $_;
        if ( $_ =~ m/^$pattern/ ) {
             $_ =~ s/$id/$newid/g;
        }
        (print NEW $_)          or die "can't write to $new: $!";
}

close(MAST)                    or die "can't close $file: $!";
close(NEW)                     or die "can't close $new: $!";

rename($file, $bak)          or die "can't rename $file to $bak: $!";
rename($new, $file)          or die "can't rename $new to $file: $!";
```

What I need to do:
Show the line before change and after change on screen and ask for user confirmation and proceed with other things later.

Please advice.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1146888

Comment: Why do you need the confirmation? That seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

If you execute your code it will show compilation error because statement is not terminated on second line.
Always use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` on top of your program after shebang line.

Here is a way to search a pattern and replace:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "file.txt";
my $newid = "500.0.0.0";
my @update;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$fh> )
{
    my ($pattern, $id) = (split(/\s+/, $line))[0, 2];  #split line to get first and third column value
    if ($pattern =~ m/4567/)
    {   
        print "Before change: $line\n";     
        $line =~ s/$id/$newid/g;  #replace id with newid when pattern is 4567
        print "After change: $line\n";
        #print "Confirm with Yes or No: ";  #here you can for confirmation
        #chomp(my $confirmation = <STDIN>);
    }
    push @update, $line;
}
close $fh;
#modify the file
open my $fhw, ">", $file or die "Couldn't modify file: $!";
print $fhw @update;
close $fhw;


----------file.txt----------
1234 ABC 100.0.0.0
4567 DEF 200.0.0.0
```

It will also print the matched line before change and after change on console. You can modify this code according to your requirement. Confirmation part is not very clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without the user confirmation element this will do it:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'm/^4567/ and s/200/500/' filename
```

Are you user you need per-line user confirmation? You can check if this did what you needed with `diff`.